# Upload Multiple image save into Database vb.net

Tags: html, asp.net, database, vb.net

Upload Multiple image save into Database vb.net

i have html code :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 margin-top-60">
    <input id="file-upload" name="files " type="file" multiple>
</div>
```

how to make that upload image path in database and without runat server ? (because if i give runat server in html program is error)

Answer (score 0):

what's the error when you're using runat="server"? you need to use runat="server" when you want to call/manipulate the objects on the code behind.

Please check this  link for a simple tutorial to uploaded images using gridview:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-images-to-folder-and-display-uploaded-images-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Hope it helps

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.